# My trackpad stopped working (not detected) after update, how do I fix this?

Tags: upgrade, touchpad, input-devices, 14.10, xinput

I updated my laptop *(Dell 'XPS 13 Developer Edition', aka 'Sputnik', the one that comes preinstalled with Ubuntu)* to 14.10. Upon reboot my trackpad didn't work. Keyboard, touchscreen and everything else works flawlessly. Plugging in a mouse works too. I tried `xinput list` and this is the result:

```
user@computer:~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNAPTICS Synaptics Large Touch Screen    id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:200a   id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:4027   id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD                      id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

From what I gather, the touchpad is not detected. Dell says that all their fixes and drivers were all upstreamed from the kernel and I can't find them, nor can I find any way of forcing Ubuntu to recognise the touchpad on the web. What's the next step from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the exact same problem !

To fix it you need to have a lookup for a line for `i2c_hid` in `/etc/modprobe.d/` folder and to comment it.

Lookup with this command for example : `grep -r i2c_hid /etc/modprobe.d/`

And you may find this :

`/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf:blacklist i2c_hid`

Then you just need to comment this line and reboot. And your trackpad will be back :-)

Comment: Didn't work. There was no such line in the folder

Comment: Worked for me as well! I'm using a Dell Developer Edition Sputnik XPS 13 purchased in 2013. Just upgraded to 16.04 and the trackpad acted as it it didn't even exist.