# Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't see the touchpad

Tags: 14.04, mouse, touchpad, asus, windows-10

I recently bought an Asus F555U with Windows 10. I immediately tried to install Ubuntu 14.04 and I started having problems. I had to go through BIOS to install it, since it didn't do it and when I finally succeded, the touchpad wasn't recognized when I was in Ubuntu. I tried every possible option, following any possible solution proposed here on AskUbuntu, but without any luck so far. 
Now the Windows partition isn't working either and I'm using an external USB Logitech mouse which is working.
Any idea on how to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot and happy holidays!

Comment: Hm... Have you tried [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/541821/my-trackpad-stopped-working-not-detected-after-update-how-do-i-fix-this) thread yet?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like missing touch-pad drivers. Ubuntu by default does not use any **proprietary drivers.**  You can check whether if there is an additional driver available for your touch-pad by using the following steps.

- Go to the **Dash** and search for **Additional drivers**
- click on the  **Additional drivers** icon.
- If there is any proprietary driver for your machine it will show up in the "Additional drivers" tab.
- If so select the driver and click on "Apply Changes" to install it.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the quick response. I already tried going to the Additional drivers tab. There are three NDIVIA drivers and it says that they're all in use. I trid to switch from one to the other, but nothing seems to change. Do you have any other suggestion? Thanks a lot!